# Hide Soft Input in OnCreate

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a TableLayout that I am dynamically adding content to in code in OnCreate.  Once the Activity creates, it is focusing on one of my dynamically created EditTexts and displaying the keyboard.  I don't want the keyboard to display until the user specifically presses one of the EditTexts.  I've tried:

```
InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
input.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);
```

But the keyboard still displays and CurrentFocus returns null.  So when I attempt to specifically point the focus to another view and then perform the above like:

```
InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) GetSystemService(InputMethodService);
title.FindFocus();
input.HideSoftInputFromWindow(CurrentFocus.WindowToken, 0);
```

CurrentFocus is still null and the keyboard still displays.  title is a TextView that I already have an instance of in code.  Can I just not give focus to a TextView or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: did you tried add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"` to your activity in the manifest?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I've looked at that, but MonoDroid doesn't seem to have SoftInputStateHidden.  Just SoftInputStateChanged which does nothing.

Comment: Yes it does, SoftInput.StateHidden http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T:Android.Views.SoftInput

Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);

Comment: "Argument Type 'Android.Views.SoftInput' is not assignable to parameter type integer"

Comment: Nevermind.  Just had to change it to Window.SetSoftInputMode((int)SoftInput.StateHidden);

Answer (score 10):

## Very Easy

1. Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file
2. In your activity add: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

For example:

```
<activity
         android:name=".package.example.MyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to AndroiManifest.xml file
2. Activity in which you want to hide keyboard add the following thing

   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"